# How to remove text between two elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, dom-manipulation

So I got the following html:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
   /
   <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
   /
   <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
   /
   <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
<ul>
```

Sadly this is generated by a Plone extension which was forked and I don't have the possibility to change the output. The list will have a different amount of elements on different pages.

All I need to do is remove the slashed between the list elements.
I couldn't come up with a good solution till now.

Is there a simple an powerful solution to do this with Javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter out all the next nodes ([nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Node.nodeType) == 3) then remove them using [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
$('ul').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VekQa/)

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! I don't really have an idea why this works but it does. :)

Comment: @jurihandl read the linked documentations, you will get some idea

Comment: Ok cool. Now I get it! Thanks! I didn't even know something like this exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].textContent.replace(/\//g,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

assign the output to a string called var outPut, then

```
outPut.replace('/','');

output.replace('a><li','a></li');
```